# Go言語にてguregu/dynamodbのクエリがエラーになる: (type error) as type Error in assignment

Tags: aws, go, amazon-dynamodb

github.com/guregu/dynamoライブラリを利用してlocalのdynamodbにhashkeyで検索をかけようとしています。
テーブルはIDをhash keyとしたusersテーブルです。(range key なし)

DBアクセスは以下のコードまで問題ありません。

```
table := db.Table("users")
```

以下のような構造体に値をそれぞれ代入し

```
var user User
var readResult User

type User struct {
    ID       string 
    Email    string 
    Password string 
}
```

以下のようにクエリを発行したところエラーが発生しました。

```
err = table.Get("ID",user.ID).One(&readResult)
```

```
./main.go:140:6: cannot use table.Get("ID", user.ID).One(&readResult) (type error) as type Error in assignment
```

以下DBのメタデータです

```
{
  "AttributeDefinitions": [
    {
      "AttributeName": "ID",
      "AttributeType": "S"
    }
  ],
  "TableName": "users",
  "KeySchema": [
    {
      "AttributeName": "ID",
      "KeyType": "HASH"
    }
  ],
  "TableStatus": "ACTIVE",
  "CreationDateTime": "2021-03-12T22:50:39.758Z",
  "ProvisionedThroughput": {
    "LastIncreaseDateTime": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "LastDecreaseDateTime": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "NumberOfDecreasesToday": 0,
    "ReadCapacityUnits": 5,
    "WriteCapacityUnits": 5
  },
  "TableSizeBytes": 135,
  "ItemCount": 2,
  "TableArn": "arn:aws:dynamodb:ddblocal:000000000000:table/users"
}
```

原因がよくわからず困っております。　何卒宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
err = table.Get("ID",user.ID).One(&readResult)
```

上記の代入文が `:=` ではなく `=` になっているのが気になります。この行より上の方で変数 `err` に対して `Error` 型の値を代入していたり、変数 `err` を `Error` 型の変数として宣言したりしていませんか？　ここの `One` の返り値は `error` 型なので、代入時の型エラーが起こっていそうです。

Comment: 有難うございます！　上記の通りでした